# how to get photo url of email account user signed into android app through FirebaseAuth with Email signIn

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used Firebase Authentication with only Email/Password in an android app project. I tried to access the picture of the email account which has been used to log into the app. However, the photoUrl is null when I try these three methods below and I am testing with my own email account which I know has a profile picture.

```
    // METHOD ONE
    Uri photoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl();

    if (photoUrl != null) {
        log.d("PhotoUrl",photoUrl.toString());
    }


    // METHOD TWO
    UserInfo userInfo = mFirebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0);
    Uri photoUrl = (Uri) userInfo.getPhotoUrl();

    if (photoUrl != null) {
        log.d("PhotoUrl",photoUrl.toString());
    }


    // METHOD THREE
    for (UserInfo userInfo:mUser.getProviderData()) {

        Uri photoUrl = userInfo1.getPhotoUrl();

        if (photoUrl != null){
            break;
        }
    }

    if (photoUrl != null) {
        log.d("PhotoUrl",photoUrl.toString());
    }
```

I am able to get the name of the email account easily like this

```
    String name = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `String photoUrl = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();
`

Comment: @FaysalAhmed yes sir, i think i have in method 1. The mFirebaseAuth variable as used in the question is a field of my activity which is instantiated when a user signs in. so it has the current user in it and since the url is null, the string version would still be null or an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using Email sign in only in FirebaseAuth, so the problem happens when you try to retrieve the photo url of the user because there is no photo url for the user by default. So what you can do is you can ask user to set the photo and save the url with the FirebaseAuth (so that you can retrieve later). You can use the code below to save the photo url for the user.

```java
    UserProfileChangeRequest userProfileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName("set new display name")
                    .setPhotoUri(uri)
                    .build();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest);
```

after setting the photo url. Try getting the photo url

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was looking to reuse the profile picture from the email account and not bother a user to take a pic to setup as a profile pic, but this is a useful alternative in the mean time. Thank you !

Comment: I don't think you can reuse the same profile picture because when you use email authentication, it makes a new user account for the each email address even if its a gmail account, but when you use the Google Authentication then the information comes from the Google Auth server and then you can use such information like display name, email id, photo url etc.

Comment: oh ok, if that is the case then this might just be the only way out. though I think it would have made sense in my app to just set an image from the email that is signed in. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
```

Initialize it

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

Load the Photo Url Using Picasso in Your ImageView

```
 Picasso.get().load(mCurrentUser.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(imageView);
```